# Count distinct serialnumbers per year-month (excel)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I create a formula in Excel that makes unique serialnumbers per year-month?

The table looks like this.

[image]

I have a helping worksheet, with Year and month.

At the moment I´m using this formula, but it doesn´t take the distinct counts, only total:

```
=COUNTIFS('Consumption per charger and mon'!G:G;D2;'Consumption per charger and mon'!A:A;"<>"" ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this straightforward formula using CountA, Unique and filter functions.

I used this recently and it worked, replace it with your columns headers(g:g) if you are not using a table like mine.

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(table1[serialnumbers],
 (table1[year]={condition})*(table1[month]={condition}))))
```

Comment: This works, but please be aware that it would return 1 in case no matches are found for the condition.
You need something along the line of: `=LET(f,FILTER(A:A,
 H:H="2020-01",""),IF(SUM((f="")),0,COUNTA(UNIQUE(f))))`

Comment: Yes, very much indeed it has high chances of returning `FALSE POSITIVES`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula using <kbd>BYROW()</kbd> with <kbd>ROWS()</kbd> to avoid false positives.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J2</kbd>

```
=LET(α,UNIQUE(H2:H9),HSTACK(α,BYROW(α,LAMBDA(φ,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,H2:H9=φ)))))))
```

---

For older versions you could try using <kbd>FREQUENCY()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K5</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(J5=$H$2:$H$9,
MATCH($A$2:$A$9,$A$2:$A$9,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1)>0))
```

---

Formula needs to be filled down! Besides you need to have a column of unique year-month values.

---

Comment: Nice approach using `FREQUENCY`

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit confused by the first line in your question: *"How do I create a formula in Excel that makes unique serialnumbers per year-month?"*

But this would be another option for calculating the distinct uniques in a range:

```
=LET(f,TOCOL(IFS(H:H="2020-01",A:A),2),
     x,XMATCH(f,f),
IFERROR(SUM(N(FREQUENCY(x,x)>0)),0))
```

Or if you want to spill the unique year/months and their unique frequency:

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(TOCOL(H:H,1)),
HSTACK(u,
       MAP(u,LAMBDA(z, 
           LET(f,TOCOL(IFS(H:H=z,A:A),2),
               x,XMATCH(f,f),
       SUM(--(FREQUENCY(x,x)>0)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(H2:H9),MAP(UNIQUE(H2:H9),LAMBDA(z,COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,H2:H9=z))))))
```

or

```
=LET(a,A2:A9,b,H2:H9,c,UNIQUE(b),HSTACK(c,MAP(c,LAMBDA(z,COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(a,b=z)))))))
```

Result:

[image]